# changing the property of class file at run time

Tags: c#

how to change the property name of class file at run time which is being used as property in propertygrid

ex)

```
public class propertygrid_sample
{
    string m_DisplayString;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return m_DisplayString; }
        set { m_DisplayString = value; }
    }

    //some code to change the name

}
```

When `propertygrid.selectedobject == propertygrid_sample` class object,  then name `Text` will get displayed as property in property grid after compilation. I need `TextAlign` to be displayed when accessing the property `Text`. By making [DisplayName("TextAlign")] i able to get solution but i am expecting some code to make the change at run time

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PropertyGridDynamicProp.aspx

Comment: thank you , for your response but i didnt asked the question correctly i edited the question so, please check it

Comment: @subbiah: I read your question twice, but I think, the provided link is exactly what do you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the display name attribute

```
[DisplayName("Other Name")]
public string Text { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom [TypeDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor?view=net-6.0) attached to your class via attribute [TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionproviderattribute?view=net-6.0).

In your custom TypeDescriptor class you need override method [GetProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties?view=net-6.0) and return edited instances of [PropertyDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor?view=net-6.0) class.

All of *Descriptor classes are meta-data classes supposed to propagating the types/members with changes - such as renaming the type/member.

Some samples with *Descriptor classes:

- [Understanding the TypeDescriptor: A
  Metadata Engine for Designtime
  Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219235052/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx)
- [Dynamic Properties in the
  PropertyGrid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9250/Dynamic-Properties-in-the-PropertyGrid)